# RApache Configure Does Not Recognize R Installed with Shared Library

Tags: r, shared, rapache

All:  Apologies in advance for what I hope is an easy question.  It's been many years since I've worked in a Unix(-like) environment...

I'm trying to install RApache on a web server running the RHEL5 64-bit OS.  I've successfully installed Apache and confirmed it works.  I've also successfully installed R (R-2.13.0) with shared library.  I've confirmed that libBlas.so and libR.so are installed; location: /R/R-2.13.0/lib

However, when I try to configure RApache ( sudo ./configure --with-apache2-apxs=/usr/local/apache2/bin/ --with-R=/R/R-2.13.0/) I get the following error:

> R was not built as a shared
>   library
>  Either build it with one,
>   or use another install of R
>   configure: error: aborting!

I've reinstalled R twice now and have confirmed in libtool that it says:

> # Whether or not to build shared
>   libraries.
>  build_libtool_libs=yes

Finally, I've searched high and low for some path or flag I need to set without success.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ron

Comment: Hi Ron, I am also trying to install Rapache on CentOs5.8,I have already downloaded apache2, so How can i install Rapache and apache2 as well?

Answer (score 5):

You need to compile R with the appropriate flags. At the configure stage you need to include --enable-R-shlib  so that R is built as a shared library.

You may need to further consult appendix B1 of http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.pdf which describes further issues.

Comment: Specify the full paths to the apxs to and R as well like so:  `sudo ./configure --with-apache2-apxs=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-R=/R/R-2.13.0/bin/R`

Comment: Thanks.  On the first installation of R I failed to do that, but then I uninstalled R and reinstalled using --enable-R-shlib.  So that should not be the problem.